# Dialog List With SQLite data

Tags: android, sqlite, list, dialog

I have an code that shows me an list of items that I have in my SQLite database.

This list is opening in another screen by clicking an button. But I have some problems with that so I need to display this list in the same screen, I can't open antoher screen, so I want to use a dialog wchich will have items from my database. I was trying to modify my code but ain't get any good results.

This is my code:

```
    public List<String> populateList() {

    List<String> uGraduateNamesList = new ArrayList<String>();

    AndroidOpenDbHelper openHelperClass = new AndroidOpenDbHelper(this);

    SQLiteDatabase sqliteDatabase = openHelperClass.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = sqliteDatabase.query("RelPregRespPred", null, null,
            null, null, null, null);

    startManagingCursor(cursor);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

        String descripcionrespuesta = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(AndroidOpenDbHelper.rdescripcionrespuesta));

        UndergraduateDetailsPojo ugPojoClass = new UndergraduateDetailsPojo();

        ugPojoClass.setrDescripcionRespuesta(descripcionrespuesta);

        pojoArrayList.add(ugPojoClass);

        uGraduateNamesList.add(descripcionrespuesta);
    }

    sqliteDatabase.close();

    return uGraduateNamesList;
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    listaTodo.setAdapter(uGraduateListAdapter);
}

public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {

    Intent seleccionRespuesta = new Intent(this,
            DescripcionPregResp.class);

    UndergraduateDetailsPojo clickedObject = pojoArrayList.get(arg2);

    startActivity(seleccionRespuesta);
}
```

So, What I have to modify to display items from database in dialog?

Thanks.

Comment: fetch data from db before you reach current activity. and use that data in list view or dialog-list. try it may help you.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. At the beginning I didn't know how to do it. But after two hours of trying I figured it out and now it works correctly.